# What is meant by the term "elements of physical reality" used by EPR paper?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

I was thinking about the phenomenon of quantum entanglement. The widely accepted view of nature of reality is that of copenhagen interpretation(please correct me if I am wrong!) while Einstein pointed out that this picture lacks something called "Elements of Physical reality"

I didn't understand what EPR intended by that term. Can anyone explain it to me? Or is there any way to better understand the phenomenon of quantum entanglement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [original article](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777) by Einstein, Podolsky and Rosen includes the following paragraph:

> The elements of the physical reality cannot be determined by a priori philosophical considerations, but must be found by an appeal to results of experiments and measurements. A comprehensive definition of reality is, however, unnecessary for our purpose. We shall be satisfied with the following criterion, which we regard as reasonable. If, without in any way disturbing a system, we can predict with certainty (i.e., with probability equal to unity) the value of a physical quantity, then there exists an element of physical reality corresponding to this physical quantity. It seems to us that this criterion, while far from exhausting all possible ways of recognizing a physical reality, at least provides us with one such way, whenever the conditions set down in it occur. Regarded not as a necessary, but merely as a sufficient, condition of reality, this criterion is in agreement with classical as well as quantum-mechanical ideas of reality.

EPR didn't provide a complete definition of an element of reality, but they thought it must include being able to make predictions about it with probability 1. Since quantum mechanics doesn't always allow this EPR thought there must be some other description that improves on quantum mechanics and allows such descriptions. Later physicists figured out that any such description consistent with the predictions of quantum mechanics would have to be non-local.

AFAICT the Copenhagen interpretation gives no account of what is happening in reality to produce the outcomes of the EPR experiment, and denies that any such explanation is possible or desirable. But since there can be no such thing as checking whether an experiment has been done correctly unless there is an account of what is supposed to happen in reality in that experiment this philosophy would, if taken seriously, require abandoning physics. And furthermore, since every experiment involves physics it would undermine all of science. This is not very satisfactory.

There is an account of what is happening in reality in experiments involving entanglement. The short version is that in entanglement experiments quantum information is carried in decoherent quantum systems in such a way that the expectation values of those systems aren't dependent on that information - this is called locally inaccessible information:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

Comment: `Later physicists figured out that any such description consistent with the predictions of quantum mechanics would have to be non-local.`

Does that mean if we allow non-locality, we can have completeness? completeness in the sense that we can measure both position and momentum simultaneously with arbitrary accuracy?

Comment: How are they different when einstein say that we have to be able to *predict* with probability 1 and we can *measure* simultaneously?

Comment: @EdenZane There is no theory that fits Einstein's restrictions that reproduces or explains the predictions of quantum mechanics. There is a theory that reproduces and explains the predictions of quantum mechanics - it's called quantum mechanics. The last two papers I linked explains what's happening in entanglement experiments using quantum mechanics.

Comment: > *"they thought it must include being able to make predictions about it with probability 1."* No, they thought it sufficient. It is in the quoted text.

Answer (score 3):

> The widely accepted view of nature of reality is that of copenhagen interpretation(please correct me if I am wrong!)

I am not sure whether it is "widely accepted" today. Bohr and company tried to persuade everyone there is nothing to worry about in the EPR paper, and that was quite successful, but then later John Bell and others have shown them wrong (Bell's inequalities), and after that we have many people and papers studying quantum theory interpretations. So I think the Copenhagen philosophy is not as widely accepted today as it was while Bohr lived.

I recommend reading the EPR paper. Regarding elements of reality, EPR explain what they mean in there:

> A comprehensive definition of reality is, however, unnecessary for our purpose. We shall be satisfied with the following criterion, which we regard as reasonable. *If, without in any way disturbing a system, we can predict with certainty (i.e., with probability equal to unity) the value of a physical quantity, then there exists an element of physical reality corresponding to this physical quantity.*

Comment: Wasn't the Bell's inequality proving that the hidden variable theory is wrong? I think it was against Einsein's view of the reality.

Comment: No, the inequalities themselves are just mathematical results based on quantum theory, they do not prove any theory as "wrong". The EPR experiment (position and momentum of massive particles) and the John Bell experiment (massive particle magnetic moment components) were never done. Some experiments with light were done instead, which are generally interpreted as violating inequalities of similar type, thus pointing to nonlocal theories, either standard quantum theory or non-local hidden variables theories. However, the last word on this topic has not been said.

Comment: It would be the Copenhagen proponents who would argue that hidden variable theory instead of orthodox QT must be wrong, but David Bohm and John Bell were not satisfied by that orthodoxy. Bohm developed alternative theory (Bohmian mechanics) where particles have simulteneously position and momentum, but obey Schroedinger's equation-implied probabilities, and John Bell discovered that both orthodox quantum theory and Bohmian mechanics violate the Bell inequalities, so both are non-local theories.

Answer (score 1):

Every particle has “elements of physical reality”. We couldn’t detect them if they didn’t. These elements, also known as variables could be as simple as mass, velocity, direction, angular momentum/Polarization, oscillation/frequency, coherency/timing/linear dependence.
EPR discusses perfectly correlating two particles, and as many of these   “Elements of Physical Reality” as possible. Then sending them in different directions to be measured later. IF everyone of these unhidden variables are not perfectly correlated, then the results can be skewed.

Comment: So is that Einstein's argument, that if we have position with probability 1 and momentum with probability 0, then momentum is not  physically real  and hence such a description is not complete?

Comment: @EdenZane Momentum is an element of physical reality, it is a combination of two different elements of physical reality but it’s real

Comment: In a system, when position is known with 100% certainty, the momentum loses its status of being an element of physical reality, right?

Comment: @EdenZane According to the uncertainty principle anyway. But you were talking about EPR where two particles are perfectly correlated. Then later measuring one particle obviously allows you to know things about the other particle.

Comment: Is it not that the EPR criterion? 
`If, without in any way disturbing a
system,
we can predict with certainty
(1.e., with
probability equal to unity) the value of a physical
quantity, then there exists an element of physical
reality corresponding to this physical quantity.`

Isn't it necessary that we are able to predict with certainty simultaneously?

Comment: @EdenZane Yes that is correct

Comment: @EdenZane No, the ability of predicting the result with probability 1 is just the sufficient condition. It is not claimed to be necessary. Read the EPR paper, it's short.

Comment: If a system has two particles that are perfectly correlated, then you can, without in any way disturbing the system, predict with certainty (1.e., with probability equal to unity) the value of a physical quantity, because there does exist physical realities and knowing something about one of the particles allows you to automatically know something about the other. Without disturbing it.